# accessing child records one by one

Tags: trigger

I have a object Revenue and a child object split. A revenue can have max 3 split records.On updating Revenue record i want to update split records. I have created a map which will store Id of Revenue and split records corresponding to that id. Revenue has 3 fields sales_rep_1, sales_rep_2, sales_rep_3 and 3 fields split_percent1,2,3. my map is like -

```
List<Split__c> existingSplits = [SELECT Id, Schedule__c FROM Split__c WHERE Revenue__c IN :Trigger.new];

 Map<Id,List<Split__c>> revtoSplits = new Map<Id,List<Split__c>>();
  if(existingSplits != null){    
             for(Split__c sp : existingSplits){                                                            
                 if(!revtoSplits.containsKey(sp.Revenue__c)){
                     revtoSplits.put(sp.Revenue__c,new List<Split__c>());
                 }
                 revtoSplits.get(sp.Revenue__c).add(sp);
             }
         }
```

Now i want to access each split record one by one so that i can calculate amount for split record based on split percent.So i am using the for loops like

```
  for(Revenue__c sched: Trigger.new){

         for(Split__c spl: revtoSplits.get(sched.id)){
```

Now here i have all split records for a Revenue record but how will i perform calculations on all three split records with a different formula to calculate amount and then update them ?
Please guide.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? What kind of different formulas you are using? Explain with a single scenario what you have & what is expected.

Comment: For insert trigger i am using the below code and now for update trigger i want similar code. Rather then cloning split records i want to update them.

Comment: follow the code i have answered below for update. Hope it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

For insert trigger i am using the below code and now for update trigger i want similar code. Rather then cloning split records i want to update them.

```
    for(Revenue__c sched: Trigger.new){
    Split__c split = new Split__c(Schedule__c = sched.Id,Schedule_Date__c = sched.Schedule_Date__c);

    Double percentRemain = 100.0;
    percentRemain -= (Double) sched.Split_Percent_2__c;
    percentRemain -= (Double) sched.Split_Percent_3__c;

    Split__c split1 = split.clone();
    split1.Sales_Rep__c  = sched.Sales_Rep_1__c;
    split1.Amount_LC__c  = percentRemain * sched.Revenue_LC__c  * .01;
    split1.Amount_USD__c = percentRemain * sched.Revenue_USD__c * .01;
    splits.add(split1);

    if(sched.Sales_Rep_2__c != null){
        Split__c split2 = split.clone();
        split2.Sales_Rep__c  = sched.Sales_Rep_2__c;
        split2.Amount_LC__c  = sched.Split_Percent_2__c * sched.Revenue_LC__c  * .01;
        split2.Amount_USD__c = sched.Split_Percent_2__c * sched.Revenue_USD__c * .01;
        splits.add(split2);
    }

    if(sched.Sales_Rep_3__c != null){
        Split__c split3 = split.clone();
        split3.Sales_Rep__c  = sched.Sales_Rep_3__c;
        split3.Amount_LC__c  = sched.Split_Percent_3__c * sched.Revenue_LC__c  * .01;
        split3.Amount_USD__c = sched.Split_Percent_3__c * sched.Revenue_USD__c * .01;
        splits.add(split3);
    }
}

insert splits;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i tried the code u provided. Its throwing error at line where u have query.It is saying cant identify the relationship because u hav mentioned split__r in subquery. This is because we can access parent object fields from child object but can't do vice versa. My revenue object don't hv any custom field as split but my split object have custom field (master detail) Revenue.Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Id> setRevIds=new Set<Id>();
List<Revenue__c> lstRev = new List<Revenue__c>();
List<Split__c> lstSplitToUpdate = new List<Split__c>();

for(Revenue__c sched: Trigger.new){
    setRevIds.add(sched.id);
}

lstRev=[select id,Split_Percent_2__c,Split_Percent_3__c,Sales_Rep_1__c,Sales_Rep_2__c,
        Sales_Rep_3__c,Revenue_LC__c,Revenue_USD__c,(select id,Sales_Rep__c,Amount_LC__c,Amount_USD__c from Splits__r)
        from Revenue__c where id in :setRevIds];

for(Revenue__c sched: lstRev){

    Double percentRemain = 100.0;
    percentRemain -= (Double) sched.Split_Percent_2__c;
    percentRemain -= (Double) sched.Split_Percent_3__c;

    for(split__c sp: sched.splits__r){
        //split 1 calculation
        if(sp.Sales_Rep__c==sched.Sales_Rep_1__c){
            sp.Amount_LC__c  = percentRemain * sched.Revenue_LC__c  * .01;
            sp.Amount_USD__c = percentRemain * sched.Revenue_USD__c * .01;
        }

        //split 2 calculation
        if(sp.Sales_Rep__c==sched.Sales_Rep_2__c){
            sp.Amount_LC__c  = sched.Split_Percent_2__c * sched.Revenue_LC__c  * .01;
            sp.Amount_USD__c = sched.Split_Percent_2__c * sched.Revenue_USD__c * .01;
        }

        //split 3 calculation
        if(sp.Sales_Rep__c==sched.Sales_Rep_3__c){
            sp.Amount_LC__c  = sched.Split_Percent_3__c * sched.Revenue_LC__c  * .01;
            sp.Amount_USD__c = sched.Split_Percent_3__c * sched.Revenue_USD__c * .01;
        }
        lstSplitToUpdate.add(sp);
    }

}
if(lstSplitToUpdate.size()>0){
    update lstSplitToUpdate;
}
```